# My computer shuts down regularly?

Tags: windows-7

My computer shuts down regularly while I am using the internet, I have formatted the computer, but still I face the same issue. I use an AMD processor and a gigabyte motherboard

Comment: Sounds like your computer is overheating.  Without more information we can't help you address that problem.

Answer (score 2):

it could be your power supply unit. Try to put your processor and video card on load by playing a game on max settings but **make sure shutdown cause is not overheating** :) If it shuts down on high load it could mean that your power supply is too weak. Or does it shuts down only while surfing the net? Did you tried using another browser? Does the PC shuts down instantly or it shows windows shut down "window"?

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems, especially with laptops. I've fixed this at least once by cleaning the fans. They were clogged with dust and almost unable to turn. So no matter what was going on, the PC would eventually get too hot and shut down.

I can also recommend updating the firmware of motherboard and GPU/video adapter. I've had shutdown issues with an old PC, when it was upgraded from Windows Vista to Windows 7. That went away when the GPU was updated with new firmware. Good luck!